# Appending an encrypted file with ccrypt?

Tags: bash, encryption, append

I can read files encrypted with `ccat file` or `ccrypt -c file` in Bash with ccrypt.

How can I append an encrypted file without doing the decryption process?

Comment: ccrypt should really not be used anymore, please don't use single-man file encryption utilities that don't even have a good protocol description.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: Add your comment to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can program this, but you can probably not perform this from the command line.

The description of the protocol can be found [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/24199/1172). It uses [full block CFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Full-block_CFB) where the previous ciphertext block is encrypted again to create a stream that is XOR'ed with the plaintext.

A quick look at the Wikipedia page shows that you can just grab the last full ciphertext block, use that as IV, skip the bytes of the result used for any partial ciphertext block (if present) and then continue encrypting.

However, you'll have to program that yourself. Good luck!